# Sort for Matrix

Tags: python, sorting, matrix

I have a problem with matrix sort.

I need to create a matrix (MxM) from **input**. And create nested lists using **randrange**.

```
matrix_size = int(input("Enter size of the matrix: "))
matrix = [[randrange(1, 51) for column in range(matrix_size)] for row in range(matrix_size)]
```

Next step i should **find sum of each column of matrix.** So i do this thing:

```
for i in range(matrix_size):
sum_column = 0
for j in range(matrix_size):
    sum_column += matrix[j][i]
    print(f'{matrix[i][j]:>5}', end='')
print(f'{sum_column:>5}')
```

So problem is... that i should add sum row in the end of a matrix. But what happens to me:

```
Enter the size of the matrix: 5

   15    23    14    22    20    73
    7    26    26    27    27   160
   17    36     9    13    42   104
    1    32    41     2    29   113
   33    43    14    49    12   130
```

Yeah. It counting right but how i can add it to the end of matrix. And sort ascending to the sums of columns. Hope some of you will understand what i need. Thanks

Comment: Your indentation needs fixed. Why not use pandas or numpy? And where are you sorting anything?

Comment: @OneCricketeer By requirements i cant use any library

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```py
import numpy as np


matrix = np.array(matrix)

rowsum = matrix.sum(axis=1)    # sum of rows
idx = np.argsort(rowsum)       # permutation that makes rowsum sorted
result = np.hstack([matrix, rowsum[:, None]])    # join matrix and roswum
result = result[idx]           # sort rows in ascending order
```

for matrix

```
array([[31, 13, 29,  5,  1],
       [21,  9, 34, 31, 22],
       [13, 38, 29, 20, 50],
       [21, 12, 26,  5, 15],
       [19, 24, 38, 44, 41]])
```

would the output be:

```
array([[ 31,  13,  29,   5,   1,  79],
       [ 21,  12,  26,   5,  15,  79],
       [ 21,   9,  34,  31,  22, 117],
       [ 13,  38,  29,  20,  50, 150],
       [ 19,  24,  38,  44,  41, 166]])
```